# Reportlab link in repeating footer

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm trying to put a footer on each page of the document, like "this document was made using blablabla".

Here's how I'm trying to do it (this runs for every page):

```
    table_style_widths = [16 * mm, 220 * mm, 34 * mm]
    table = Table([
        [
            Image(logo, 14 * mm, 5.6 * mm, 'direct', 'auto', 1, 'LEFT'),
            Paragraph("<para align='left'>%s &nbsp; <link href='%s'>%s</link></para>" % (ugettext('MADE_WITH_THIS_STUFF'), url, link_text),
                      self._styles['FooterText']),
            Paragraph("<para align='right'><b>%s</b></para>" % ugettext('NTH_PAGE') % page_number,
                      self._styles['BodyText'])
        ]
    ], style=[
        ('HALIGN', (0, -1), (0, -1), 'RIGHT'),
        ('HALIGN', (1, -1), (1, -1), 'LEFT')
    ], colWidths=table_style_widths)
    table.wrapOn(self, 0, 0)
    table.drawOn(self, 14 * mm, 2 * mm)
```

If I don't wrap it in the `link` tags, it works perfectly, but once I do the error of `ValueError: redefining named object: 'Annot.NUMBER1'` comes up.

I've been trying to extract the `Paragraph` to a higher level, so it's generated only once, but that didn't help. I've also tried to just put the `www.site.com` as plain text, as I read ReportLab should automatically make it a link, but that doesn't work either (no error thrown in this case, but doesn't get converted to a hyperlink).